# Convert 3D RGB np array to 2D binary

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am currently trying to find an efficient way of taking an RGB image and converting it to a binary/ black and white image. To the likes of:

```
RGBnp = [
          [[255, 255, 255], [0  , 0  , 0  ], [0  , 0  , 0  ]],
          [[255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255]],
          [[255, 255, 255], [0  , 0  , 0  ], [255, 255, 255]]
        ]

BinaryNP = [
             [1, 0, 0],
             [1, 1, 1],
             [1, 0, 1]
           ]
```

This is so I may utilise a distance transform to find a region of interest in the image. I have attempted more manual methods, like loops, though these are incredibly slow when being done to a matrix of size 480,640,3. I have searched for a reshaping algorithm that removes the last array of the shape whilst keeping some data, but to no avail.

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
RGBnp = np.array(RGBnp)
RGBnp[RGBnp == 255] = 1
BinaryNP = RGBnp[:,:,0]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that quick response, this is exactly as needed!